# JS doesn't load

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Ok so I found the hamburger I want on codepen, the html and css works perfectly but the js won't load for some reason.

This is the link to the codepen    codepen.io/sergioandrade/pen/onkub

and my files and folders are in order. My question is do I just copy the js as it is or should I add something I don't understand why this isn't working.

Thank you all in advance

Comment: By the way I posted the script src inside and in the bottom of the body tag like this 
script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

Comment: The js code includes jQuery. Did you include it too?

Comment: Check your browser console if there was any error.
Load jQuery before your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this Codepen uses jQuery (by the use of the `$` function). Have you included jQuery in your code? You can do so by including the following line in the `<head>` section of your HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```